# Symfony2 with BraincraftedBootstrapBundle: toggle button does not open when clicked

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I don't understand why the same code works in my php blog but not in Symfony2 with Braincrafted... installed with Assetic (I've read the discussions on toggle/collapsible buttons not clickable). In both cases, I've got data-target="#main-menu" and the DIV below have the same id="main-menu". Any idea?
My code in Symfony2:
    
        
            
            
                
                    Toggle navigation

```
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-menu">
            <ul class="nav nav-justified navbar-inverse">
                <!-- if connection page, class name = active -->
                <li class="{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'fos_user_security_login'?'active':' ' }}">
                    <a href="{{ path( 'fos_user_security_login' ) }}">
                        {{ 'nav.login'|trans|upper }}
                    </a>
                </li>

                <!-- if registration page, class name = active -->
                <li class="{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'fos_user_registration_register'?'active':' ' }}">
                    <a href="{{ path( 'fos_user_registration_register' ) }}">
                        {{ 'nav.register'|trans|upper }}
                    </a>
                </li>

                <!-- if passwordForgotten page, class name = active -->
                <li class="{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'fos_user_resetting_request'?'active':' ' }}">
                    <a href="{{ path( 'fos_user_resetting_request' ) }}">
                        {{ 'nav.passwordForgotten'|trans|upper }}
                    </a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

My code in my php blog:
    
        
            
            
                
                    Toggle navigation
                    
                    
                    
                
                Blog MVC</a>
                -->

```
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-menu">
            <ul class="nav nav-justified navbar-inverse">
                <li class=<?php echo (isset($onLoginPage) && ($onLoginPage == true) ? 'active' : '') ?>>
                    <a href="index.php?controller=user&action=login_page">
                        <?php echo strtoupper( "se connecter" ); ?>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=<?php echo (isset($onRegistration)&& ($onRegistration==true) ? 'active' : '') ?>>
                    <a href="index.php?controller=user&action=registration_page">
                        <?php echo strtoupper( "s'inscrire" ); ?>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=<?php echo (isset($onPasswordForgotten) && ($onPasswordForgotten == true) ? 'active' : '') ?>>
                    <a href="index.php?controller=user&action=pwd_forgotten">
                        <?php echo strtoupper( "mot de passe oublie" ); ?>
                    </a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Good points: about (2), there are no javascript errors in the developer tool. About (1), that seems to be the problem: all bootstrap css have been loaded but no bootstrap js file! Yet there are all present in web/js. This are the 2 blocks in my base.html.twig:    {% block stylesheets %}
        {% stylesheets
            'css/*'
            'bundles/blog/css/*'
            filter='cssrewrite' %}
            {# Bootstrap files from BraincraftedBootstrapBundle #}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
        {% endstylesheets %}
    {% endblock %}

Comment: and for javascript:    {% block javascripts %}
        {% javascripts '@BlogBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
            {# my javascript file myfunctions.js #}
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
        {% endjavascripts %}

        {% javascripts 'js/*' %}
            {# including all JS file compiled by Assetic #}
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
        {% endjavascripts %}
    {% endblock %}

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML markup is the same between a working version and a broken version, I would check that:

1) The bootstrap javascript is being loaded onto the page (in the network tab of developer tools); and
2) There are no javascript errors in the developer tools console that could be affecting other JS on the page

Comment: Sorry Cristian, I added my comment in the wrong place. But yes, I wonder why no bootstrap js file has been loaded but all css have been. I can see all bootstrap and jquery files in web/js and all css in web/css but only the css are loaded. As all templates inherit from base.html.twig, I imagine something is wrong in my syntax (see above), I just cannot see what. If anyone has an idea, help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: \@BlogBundle should probably be \@ExampleBlogBundle (where Example is the name of your app that you are using in your namespaces. Other than that it's hard to tell why your js isn't loading. I've made the mistake of sometimes putting changes in the wrong file. I'd make sure you're in the right file first by hard-coding a title tag to something like 'test', then progressively work one step at a time (hard-code the file to ensure the functionality works, put the file in a javascripts block with a hard-coded url and ensure it works, finally use the \@ notation and ensure it works.